# Autocomplete blender script using jedi-vim

Tags: python, vim, blender, jedi-vim

I recently added jedi-vim to my plug-in arsenal. It works just fine for the standard modules, but is unable to find bpy and bmesh stuff.

So in the blender console I took the output of `print(sys.path)` and added it to a vimscript function in a `.lvimrc` file, like this:

```
function BpyPath()
    python sys.path.append('/home/john/src/blender-2.77-linux-glibcl211-x86_64/2.77/python/lib/python3.5')
    ...
endfunction
```

Now it works better. Typing `bpy.` gives me:

[image]

But typing `bpy.context.` still gives me: **-- Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found**

**Versions:**

- Blender: 2.77a 64-bit linux
- OS: Fedora 22
- Python: 2.7.10
- Vim: 7.4

I am not a very advanced python or vim user, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: What you wanted to be shown?

Comment: @SibiCoder Functions and variables in bpy.context namespace

Comment: Can you give an example snippet with littel explanation of it and show me what you want?

Comment: @SibiCoder I cant think of a way to better describe my problem other than: I want to use autocompletion in Vim when writing blender scripts. So I need help setting up jedi-vim.

Comment: You may have to set path. Tell me where your file resides, what you wanted to show as an example( function or variable), also, put the output of `:set path ` here. Also, add the path of the file here.

Comment: @SibiCoder Running print(bpy.__file__) from blenders own python console gives the output: /home/john/src/blender-2.77a-linux-glibc211-x86_64/2.77/scripts/modules/bpy/__init__.py

Comment: Print the output of `:set path` execute in vim command line.

Comment: path=.,/usr/include,,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114539/discussion-between-john-and-sibicoder).

Comment: Include your home path in PATH variable in your .vimrc file and check. Like this : `:set path+=/home/John/src/**5`. **5 means 5 levels of subdirectiores.

Comment: You could try to set `jedi.settings.auto_import_modules.append('bpy')`. `context` might not be completable, because it's too complicated for Jedi to resolve. The command above will just import bpy for all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized that there's not a lot of hope, because you're already talking to a compiled (C/C++) module.

If `dir(bpy.context)` (in a Python shell) doesn't give you the completions that you want, Jedi will also not be able to infer this information. If `dir` gives you something reasonable, just create an issue in the Jedi issue tracker. It would be a bug, IMO.

I'm planning a plugin system for Jedi, to make it possible to use Jedi with such use cases as well. But this will probably take two years.

Comment: Nope. That did not give any useful output. I'll just wait the two years. Thanks.

Comment: Dave - I expect you will get more questions about blender auto-complete as this is coming up more often. See my answer to this as blender's bpy module is not a normal python module and would need extra setup outside of your project.

Answer (score 2):

This often catches people out. Blender's `bpy` module is a compiled module created from source code within blender. The binary for the module is merged into blender's binary and is not made available outside of the python interpreter within blender.

It is possible to compile blender yourself and enable an option to build [blender as a python module](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule) that you can import into any python interpreter, and will probably be the solution you are looking for.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37207627/2684771) you can also find some links to other answers that have tips for using eclipse and pycharm with blender that may be of some help.

Answer (score -1):

Blender Python Text Editor, `IDE` there is this new tool **Bacutor**, has `intellisense`, `syntax Highlight` and more

http://bacutor.freeiz.com

Comment: try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others